# Xcode NSKeyedUnarchiver Memory Leak SKNode Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, nskeyedunarchiver

After days and days of researching and trying my best, I have not found a solution to a memory leak problem. I have already tried very many ideas I found in this forum but nothing seemed to help me out.

I load my GameScene.sks with this code like everyone else does:

```
extension SKNode {

class func unarchiveFromFile(file:String) -> SKNode? {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "sks") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do {
            let sceneData = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe)
            let archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: sceneData)
            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObject(forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! SKNode
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

and i am using it in my code here:

```
func load(level: String) {
    if let levelNode = SKNode.unarchiveFromFile(file: level) {
        mapNode = levelNode
        mapNode.name = "MapNode"
        self.worldLayer.addChild(mapNode)
        loadTileMap()
    }
}
```

If I leave out the line `self.worldLayer.addChild(mapNode)` everything works perfectly and the memory usage will never rise. But if I use it (I need it!), memory keeps climbing and climbing.

With use of Instruments it says that the line with `let scene = archiver.decodeObject(forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! SKNode` causes all the memory leaks.

Unfortunately I do not get it and have not managed to remove my leaks.

I appreciate all help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is old,  you do not need that extension anymore, just use `SKNode(fileNamed:level)`

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I tried it and at least I know now that the extension doesn‘t cause the leaks because with just adding SKNode(fileNamed: level) memory leak is exactly the same as before. Removing it before going to a new scene doesnt‘t help. There somehow must be a steong reference between my scene and the mapNode.   Any ideas for getting that fixed?

Comment: do you have a gameScene.swift file?  Do not do anything in the inits because that is bugged

Comment: urm yeah of course. What is the bug? I initialize it with size. Instead working with optionals and initializing them in the code?

Comment: I mean do you override the inits.  It creates GameScene twice, and if you have things in the init, it would ever deinit.  My guess is the 2 scenes retain each other

Comment: I dont use override init. I use init(with size) and required init. And also the didMove method.

Comment: if you are using required init, then you are overriding it. Also, you shouldn't be touching init with size because you are loading an SKS file.  Whatever you are doing in the init, move it to the did move to view

Comment: Okay I will give it a try. How do I set the size of the scene to fit on all devies? Before I did it with init and view.bounds.size

Comment: SceneKit does it automatically for you, the tutorial you used just sucks.  It will either scale the scene or resize (You probably want scale) based on on what you put in view.scaleMode

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still couldn´t fix the issue but I found out some things. I can put everything I want in the scene editor (.sks) file and I will not get any memory leaks. Even Tile Maps. But as soon as I put only one tile in some tilemap memory leaks are rising very high again. How can one single tile cause all those issues?